# Updating SVG text nodes dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg

There are some SVG text labels in a picture I'd like to update. I get all of them by calling a group first and then substracting its children to get pure text nodes:

```
let textLabels = document.getElementById('texts').children
```

So, I got an HTMLCollection containing all my text nodes. Then, I'd like to update/set new texts on these nodes, so I'm trying:

```
Array.from(textLabels).forEach(function (i) {
   i.textContent(...)
}
```

..., and I get: `TypeError: i.textContent is not a function`

`textLabels` array looks like:

```
0: text#label_0
1: text#label_1
2: text#label_2
```

How should I set texts on these?

Comment: @Mark_M: please post it as an answer, it helped :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textContent` is not a function. You can assign a value directly to it:

```
Array.from(textLabels).forEach(function (i) {
   i.textContent = 'some text'
}
```

More documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent